# How can I add specific validation to an ExpressionEngine form?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation, expressionengine

Within an ExpressionEngine template page, made by other developers several years ago, we have this form:

```
        <div id="sidebar_loader" class="dnone">
                <div class="sb-bg">
                    <div class="sb-bg-bottom">
                        <h2 class="findloc">Find Location Nearest You</h2>
                        <span class="findloc-content">
                            To find your nearest Carriage Services location enter your <b>City 
                            and State</b> or your <b>ZIP code</b>.
                        </span>
                        <div class="hbar w280px"></div> 
                        <div class="searchContent">
                            <div class="searching">Now Searching for the closest locations to you.</div>
                            <div class="hbar w280px"></div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /sb-bg end -->               
            </div><!-- /sidebar_loader end -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="sb-bg">
                <div class="sb-bg-bottom">                      
                    <h2 class="findloc">Find Location Nearest You</h2>
                    <span class="findloc-content">
                        To find your nearest Carriage Services location enter your <b>City 
                        and State</b> or your <b>ZIP code</b>.
                    </span>
                    <div class="hbar w280px"></div>     
                    <div class="search_row">
                        <div class="search_caption">Zip Code</div>
                        <input type="text" id="address" class="textbox" name="address" value="{exp:mx_google_map:searched_zip}" />              
                    </div>  
                    <br class="clear">
                    <div class="search_row">
                        <div class="search_caption">Distance</div>
                        <div class="selCont">
                            <?php 
                                    $selected = "{exp:mx_google_map:searched_radius1}";
                                    if($selected == "")
                                    {
                                        $selected = "30";                               
                                    }
                            ?>

                            <select name="radius1" id="fradius">
                                <option value="10"  <?php if ( $selected == "10") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>10 MILES</option>
                                <option value="15"  <?php if ( $selected == "15") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>15 MILES</option>
                                <option value="20"  <?php if ( $selected == "20") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>20 MILES</option>
                                <option value="25"  <?php if ( $selected == "25") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>25 MILES</option>
                                <option value="31"  <?php if ( $selected == "31") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>30 MILES</option>
                                <option value="50"  <?php if ( $selected == "50") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>50 MILES</option>
                                <option value="100" <?php if ( $selected == "100") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>100 MILES</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search_row" style="position:relative;">
                        <span style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:120px;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#313131;#top:5px;">or</span>
                        <div class="hbar w280px"></div> 
                    </div>
                    <br class="clear">
                    <div class="search_row">
                        <div class="search_caption">City</div>
                        <input type="text" id="city" class="textbox" name="city" value="{exp:mx_google_map:searched_city}"/>                
                    </div>
                    <br class="clear">
                    <div class="search_row">
                        <div class="search_caption">State</div>
                        <div class="selCont state" id="Sstate">
                            <?php 
                                    $selectedState = "{exp:mx_google_map:searched_state}";                                      
                            ?>
                            <select id="state" name="state" >
                                <option value="AL" <?php if ( $selectedState == "AL") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>> Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AK" <?php if ( $selectedState == "AK") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AZ" <?php if ( $selectedState == "AZ") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Arizona</option>
                                <option value="AR" <?php if ( $selectedState == "AR") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Arkansas</option>
                                <option value="CA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "CA") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>California</option>
                                <option value="CO" <?php if ( $selectedState == "CO") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Colorado</option>
                                <option value="CT" <?php if ( $selectedState == "CT") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Connecticut</option>
                                <option value="DE" <?php if ( $selectedState == "DE") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Delaware</option>
                                <option value="FL" <?php if ( $selectedState == "FL") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Florida</option>
                                <option value="GA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "GA") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Georgia</option>                                   
                                <option value="HI" <?php if ( $selectedState == "HI") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Hawaii</option>
                                <option value="ID" <?php if ( $selectedState == "ID") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Idaho</option>
                                <option value="IL" <?php if ( $selectedState == "IL") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Illinois</option>
                                <option value="IN" <?php if ( $selectedState == "IN") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Indiana</option>
                                <option value="IA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "IA") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Iowa</option>
                                <option value="KS" <?php if ( $selectedState == "KS") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Kansas</option>
                                <option value="KY" <?php if ( $selectedState == "KY") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Kentucky</option>
                                <option value="LA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "LA") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Louisiana</option>
                                <option value="ME" <?php if ( $selectedState == "ME") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Maine</option>
                                <option value="MD" <?php if ( $selectedState == "MD") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Maryland</option>
                                <option value="MA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "MA") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Massachusetts</option>
                                <option value="MI" <?php if ( $selectedState == "MI") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Michigan</option>
                                <option value="MN" <?php if ( $selectedState == "MN") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Minnesota</option>
                                <option value="MS" <?php if ( $selectedState == "MS") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Mississippi</option>
                                <option value="MO" <?php if ( $selectedState == "MO") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Missouri</option>
                                <option value="MT" <?php if ( $selectedState == "MT") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Montana</option>
                                <option value="NE" <?php if ( $selectedState == "NE") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Nebraska</option>
                                <option value="NV" <?php if ( $selectedState == "NV") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Nevada</option>
                                <option value="NH" <?php if ( $selectedState == "NH") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>New Hampshire</option>
                                <option value="NJ" <?php if ( $selectedState == "NJ") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>New Jersey</option>
                                <option value="NM" <?php if ( $selectedState == "NM") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>New Mexico</option>
                                <option value="NY" <?php if ( $selectedState == "NY") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>New York</option>
                                <option value="NC" <?php if ( $selectedState == "NC") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>North Carolina</option>
                                <option value="ND" <?php if ( $selectedState == "ND") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>North Dakota</option>
                                <option value="OH" <?php if ( $selectedState == "OH") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Ohio</option>
                                <option value="OK" <?php if ( $selectedState == "OK") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Oklahoma</option>
                                <option value="OR" <?php if ( $selectedState == "OR") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Oregon</option>
                                <option value="PA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "PA") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option value="RI" <?php if ( $selectedState == "RI") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Rhode Island</option>
                                <option value="SC" <?php if ( $selectedState == "SC") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>South Carolina</option>
                                <option value="SD" <?php if ( $selectedState == "SD") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>South Dakota</option>
                                <option value="TN" <?php if ( $selectedState == "TN") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Tennessee</option>
                                <option value="TX" <?php if ( $selectedState == "TX") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Texas</option>
                                <option value="UT" <?php if ( $selectedState == "UT") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Utah</option>
                                <option value="VT" <?php if ( $selectedState == "VT") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Vermont</option>
                                <option value="VA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "V A") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WA" <?php if ( $selectedState == "WA") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Washington</option>
                                <option value="WV" <?php if ( $selectedState == "WV") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>West Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WI" <?php if ( $selectedState == "WI") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Wisconsin</option>
                                <option value="WY" <?php if ( $selectedState == "WY") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Wyoming</option>               
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="search_row">
                        <div class="search_caption">Distance</div>
                        <div class="selCont">
                            <?php 
                                    $selected = "{exp:mx_google_map:searched_radius2}";
                                    if($selected == "")
                                    {
                                        $selected = "30";                               
                                    }
                            ?>

                            <select name="radius2" id="radius">
                                <option value="10"  <?php if ( $selected == "10") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>10 MILES</option>
                                <option value="15"  <?php if ( $selected == "15") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>15 MILES</option>
                                <option value="20"  <?php if ( $selected == "20") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>20 MILES</option>
                                <option value="25"  <?php if ( $selected == "25") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>25 MILES</option>
                                <option value="31"  <?php if ( $selected == "31") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>30 MILES</option>
                                <option value="50"  <?php if ( $selected == "50") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>50 MILES</option>
                                <option value="100" <?php if ( $selected == "100") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>100 MILES</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br class="clear">
                    <?php 
                        $funeral = "{exp:mx_google_map:searchBy_Funeral}";
                        if( $funeral == "" )
                        {
                            $funeral = 0;
                        }

                        $cemetaries = "{exp:mx_google_map:searchBy_Cemetaries}";
                        if( $cemetaries == "" )
                        {
                            $cemetaries = 3;
                        }
                    ?>
                    <div class="hbar w280px"></div> 
                    <div class="search_row">                    
                        <span>Search For:</span>
                        <div id="funeral" class="check">Funeral Homes</div>
                        <div id="cemetaries" class="check">Cemeteries</div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="funeral" value="<?php echo $funeral; ?>"  id="fhidden">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cemetaries" value="<?php echo $cemetaries; ?>"  id="chidden">

                        <span><input type="image" src="/images/search.png" style="margin:20px 0 -20px 170px;" onclick="loader()"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <br class="clear">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /sb-bg end -->                       
        </div><!-- /sidebarend -->
```

It needs to be modified so that it won't work if both the city and zip code fields are empty. At least one has to be filled. Not sure how to do this with ExpressionEngine. My javascript and PHP are not that good.

Can anyone advise on a good way to implement this validation?

Comment: The code you have pasted is only the form and has no validation logic. If you have javascript validation it should be inculded in the page somewhere. The PHP validation in EE can be done in quite a few ways depending if you are using chanels, safecracker or if it is just a standalone form?

Comment: You might want to post this to the ExpressionEngine specific StackExchange site for a faster response: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/